# USB-C port only works if devices plugged during boot, and won't be recognized if Windows is running

Tags: windows, boot, usb, drivers, usb-c

My Dell XPS 9560 has an USB-C port, and it doesn't work correctly. If I plug in a device during boot (I mean before pressing power button), Windows can recognize it and things work normally. However, if Windows already boots and is running, Device Manager shows driver (USB 3.1 extensible), then it's gone immediately and I can't use the USB device.
The problem has become popular in community and it seems to be caused by Windows 2004 update and still presents in 20H2 update.
Some users find out the problem might relate to power manager function of Windows. Disabling the USB selective suspend setting in Windows power option can solve it, but has side effects (sometimes it doesn't work, and plugging in causes audio distortion). https://www.dell.com/community/XPS/XPS-15-9560-Type-C-not-working-after-2004-Windows-update/td-p/7651784/page/3

My question is: How can I trace the cause of this problem? I have tried using EventGhost to see what's happening during the plugging in but it shows nothing. Do you have any idea to resolve it completely? Thank you.

Comment: Is the machine on a domain? Could there be a group policy in effect which is disabling USB devices?

Comment: No, this is my personal computer, Windows 10 Home (no official group policy). Before 2004 update, the 1909 version worked pretty well. As I describe, it works if device is plugged in during boot, and failed if windows is already running.

Comment: I have the same problem, and disabling the USB selective suspend doesn't solve It. The problem also happens in Linux because it's a hardware problem.

Comment: @skan it seems to happen at the firmware level, and Dell doesn't really care to fix it.